# How can I redirect localhost/s to localhost/s/web/index.php to using mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm developing a little web application, my directory structure was something like this:

```
htdocs/s/index.php
htdocs/s/views/
htdocs/s/vendors/
```

and I used this .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options -MultiViews
   Options +FollowSymlinks
   RewriteEngine On   
   RewriteBase /s/
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

This way I can enter `localhost/s/aaaa` to access at `localhost/s/index.php/aaaa`. But I've changed my directory structure to something like this:

```
htdocs/s/web/index.php
htdocs/s/views/
htdocs/s/vendors/
```

And I don't know how to make the .htaccess to redirect `localhost/s/aaa` to `localhost/s/web/index.php/aaa.`

I tried a lot of things but without result. Anybody here that knows more about .htaccess and mod_rewrite can help me?

EDIT: It seems that it's imposible to setup it with my lampp server or something like that. But how the heck people manage to make WordPress, Joomla and other CMS do it?

It's really not that important in a developing environment, but when I'll upload it to the Internet there's to be some way that hide all the libraries and internals of the application to the web visitor. I mean everybody does it, right? So how it can be done?

EDIT 2: For some weird reason it cannot be one in my home server, so I'm back to my previous directory structure and make a nasty hack with a .htaccess with "deny For All" in the directories that want to hide. Thay'll not be a lot hidden, but I cannot find any other solution...

Answer (score 0):

If rewrite rules you have provided were working fine for you, then this should work fine as well:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
   RewriteEngine On   
   RewriteBase /s/
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I tried and it don't work, I get a 404 error with localhost/s but it works with localhost/s/index.php. It's a little bit weird.

Comment: I noticed that localhost/s/index.php/aaa don't work either, but localhost/s/web/aaa work's fine.

Comment: Where do you have this .htaccess file saved (which folder)? In any case -- why don't you setup virtual host for a site and access it via some fake domain name (like `mysite.dev`) which you can easily do via `hosts` file? This will save you from a lot of headache.

Comment: 1) Then it will not work if accessed like `localhost/s` (without trailing slash -- as `localhost/s` does not equal to `localhost/s/` --you have rewrite base set up, remember?). 2) What do you mean by "it does not work with localhost/s/index.php/aaa" ? Do you have `localhost/s/index.php` file present?

Comment: What? I just want that the http://localhost/s/web/index.php/ can be accessed using http://localhost/s/ and if I use http://localhost/s/something works as if I enter http://localhost/s/web/index.php/something. I know it's possible, mod_rewrite is used for that, don't it?

Comment: Yes -- add TRAILING SLASH after `/s` (`localhost/s/`) and it should work. Technically `localhost/s` will not trigger rewrite rules in `localhost/s/.htaccess` because it is OUTSIDE of `localhost/s/` (yes, trailing slash makes the difference). And you have not provided an answer for #2 -- Do you have `localhost/s/index.php` file present?

Comment: To the 2nd one, no. I want to open webroot/s/web/index.php not webroot/s/index.php, it's the whole point of this. The trailing slug, don't worked before you asked, and I don't think it will work after... so in this case it's not really relevant. I arriving to the conclussion that it's not possible, maybe because the config of my server, maybe because it's not the way to solve it. How the people usually solve this problems? Because wordpress does something like this and there have to be a way.

Comment: If you want `localhost/s` to work as well -- you have to create some rewrite rule and put it in .htaccess at `localhost/.htaccess` to redirect `localhost/s` to `localhost/s/`.

Comment: I will end up going back to my previous approach and hide all the directories with "deny from all" maybe it'll work.

Comment: @kevinspencer33 I do not understand what is the problem you are having? I have just re-tested it on my local Apache ... and it works exactly the same: `localhost/s/` gets rewritten to `localhost/s/web/index.php` while request to `localhost/s` (without trailing slash) shows 403 error. Try placing `DirectorySlash On` in your server config (or in .htaccess in `localhost/.htaccess`) to have Apache issue 301 redirect from `localhost/s` to `localhost/s/`. WordPress .. if you set it up similarly will work the same -- I did it before, so I know it.

Comment: I'm very lost because it don't work for me, and I don't understand why. I'll use a Deny For All in every directory that I don't want to show up, because the other way don't work in my case. It's no the best way but it's the only one that works in my home server. Anyway, thanks LazyOne for trying to help me.